# Use different textfield controller in listview builder

Tags: flutter, listview, textfield

I've create a `TextField` inside a `ListView.builder`. When user tap the button, it will add the new `TextField`. How do I use different `TextField` controller inside a `ListView.builder`? Thanks.

codes

```
ListView.builder(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: categoryCount,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return TextField(
        // controller: 
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Amount',
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      );
    });
```

Comment: You can create a list of TextFieldController and access each one with index passed as parameter in itemBuilder function

Comment: I was thinking bout that. I'll try it, thanks. @GuilhermeGabanelli

Comment: You're welcome, I'll write as a answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of TextFieldController and access each one with index passed as parameter in itemBuilder function

Answer (score 0):

Try [This](https://blog.devgenius.io/add-remove-textformfields-dynamically-in-flutter-5bef6948e778) answer hope its helpful to you. and try below answer also. you used Stateful Widget

Create variables

```
var name = <TextEditingController>[];
var cards = <Card>[];
```

Create init() function

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cards.add(createCard());
  }
```

Create method for createing TextEditingController

```
  createCard() {
    var nameController = TextEditingController();
    name.add(nameController);
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: nameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: ' Name',
              hintText: 'Add Name',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Create your Widget:

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cards.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return cards[index];
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Add'),
              onPressed: () => setState(
                () => cards.add(
                  createCard(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```